# Work process for data passing in VueJS 2 application

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am pretty new to VueJS 2, so wanted to see if I am working in the correct way.  I have a system where someone uploads a file that contains data, which will then be used to create charts.  So I display the uploaded files to them

```
<tr v-for="file in files.data" :key="file.id">
     //file information
     <td>
         <router-link :to="{ name: file.chart, params: { fileName: file.name }}" 
                tag="a" exact> View Results
         </router-link>
     </td>
</tr>
```

So you can see I have a link in the table, that directs them to the chart page for the file they uploaded.  It includes the params for the file name to be loaded.

On the chart page, I get the params within the created method.  I then pass these to the component for the chart to be displayed

```
<template>
    <div>
       //some information
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12" id="parentDiv">
                <barchart :file-name = this.fileName></barchart>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Barchart from '../charts/Barchart';
    export default {
        components: {
            'barchart': Barchart
        },
        data() {
            return {
                fileName: ''
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.fileName = this.$route.params.fileName;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Finally, I have the Barchart component. This is what creates the chart based on the file uploaded data.

```
<script>
    import * as d3 from 'd3';

    export default {
        props: {
            fileName: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        },
        methods: {
            createBarChart() {
              //d3 to create chart using the file that was uploaded
            } 
        },
        created() {
            let vm = this;
            d3.json('storage/' + this.fileName)
                .then(function (data) {
                    vm.createBarChart(data);
                }).catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

To me, there seems to be a lot of passing of data from one component to the next.  I pass it from the files display component (which displays all uploaded files), then to the page for the chart, which then passes it to the chart component.

The other issue is, if I am on the charts page, and I refresh the page, then the chart no longer has the filename prop and therefore the chart does not render.  How would I handle this
situation?

Any advice appreciated

Comment: This flow looks pretty typical to me and is necessary to keep components modular.  The one suggestion I do have is to [pass your route params as props](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html).  This alleviates the need to get the param in the `created` hook.

Comment: Thanks, will implement props instead of params.  Do you have any suggestions about the page refresh losing the props?  I have seen talk about implementing local storage, not sure this is the best option?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the page refresh issue will be solved by making the route params props.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are losing the chart on refresh is due to the use of the created method.

In your chart component remove the entire created method and reference the route param directly in your barchart reference, like so:

```
<template>
    <div>
       //some information
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12" id="parentDiv">
                <barchart :file-name="$route.params.fileName"></barchart>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Barchart from '../charts/Barchart';
    export default {
        components: {
            'barchart': Barchart
        },
        data() {
            return {

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this, but still losing the data on page refresh

Comment: What does your filename look like? Have you considered adding it to the url? I can post an example of using path parameters in your router. That would manage the state better and the url could be copied and pasted for example to send in an email etc...

Comment: I am using this with Laravel, so the filename is a path to the storage folder e.g. storage/user/filename.csv

Comment: Are you building this as a single page application within VueJS? This is really becoming more of an architecture question. If you are serving vue ugtilizing laravels router I would recommend reading through https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html

If you are using Vue's router, perhaps you could serve an ID or slug of the file name using dynamic routing variable (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html) instead of a param. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to manage the data passing from parent to some deeply nested child.

Before you decide you want to persist the file in the nested component, you may want to consider if this is good UX (*does it make sense that when the user refreshes the page, the old file they had uploaded is still cached?*) You can look into using [`localStorage`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/client-side-storage.html) to store things locally so that upon refresh, the data is still there without needing the user to re-enter it.